# How to make regular expression to ignore all whitespaces and line breaks

Tags: regex

kindly help me with my regular expression I am new to it. I am checking for the presence of email in a text and textarea field. My regex works when I check it without putting spaces in between email string. for example:
               raza chohan    @     gm ail  .  co m

but I want it to ignore whitespaces and linebreaks wherever they occur. Following is my regex:

**`/^(.(?!([a-z0-9._-](\s|\r\n|\n|\r){0,}(at|@)(\s|\r\n|\n|\r){0,}[a-z0-9._-]{2,}(\s|\r\n|\n|\r){0,}[a-z0-9._-]{0,}(\s|\r\n|\n|\r){0,}(\.|dot)(\s|\r\n|\n|\r){0,}[a-z]{2,})))*$/im`**

Kindly update this regex to avoid or skip whitespaces and line breaks . Thank you!!

Comment: could you explain `My regex works but I want it to ignore whitespaces and linebreaks wherever they occur` with an example?

Comment: Your regex is embedded with a negative look ahead already that results in ignoring whitespace. So, do you want the inverse of that, to recognize whitespace? Also, your regex contains `\s` and the way you are using it, already includes `\r?\n|\r`.

Comment: Does your regex cater for precisely the characters admissible in email adresses ? You may wish to consult [the pertinent rfc 5322, section 3.4.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322). Also consider to perform the check by other means than regex alone (eg. to allow for easier maintenance when taking into account more anti-spam spelling variations). Nb:  `{0,}` is equivalent to `*`.

Comment: Please can you check your tags.  You claim to be using `r`, but this isn't an R-style regular expression (the backslashes arent doubled).  Did you mean `qt`?

Answer (score 0):

As collapsar mentioned, regular expressions are not the only tool you can use.  It isn't entirely clear from the question how you want the whitespace matching to change, but consider stripping whitespace (or at least newlines) from your string before you check for the email addresses.  Then your regular expression can be simplified.

Also, using [`\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (that matches a word boundary) may be easier than explicitly mentioning all types of whitespace.

There is good advice on email matching on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the Dot metachar does not include newlines by default.
Not sure about R, but you do have the `//m` flag set (multi line mode)
that may mean the dot includes newlines.

Either way, you can get the equivalent by moving all the \s|\r\n stuff into a separate alternation.

This is your original with the negative lookahead after the match char.

```
 # /^(.(?!([a-z0-9._-](at|@)[a-z0-9._-]{2,}[a-z0-9._-]{0,}(\.|dot)[a-z]{2,})|\s))*$/im

 ^ 
 (
      . 
      (?!
           (
                [a-z0-9._-] 
                ( at | @ )
                [a-z0-9._-]{2,} 
                [a-z0-9._-]{0,} 
                ( \. | dot )
                [a-z]{2,} 
           )
        |  
           \s 
      )
 )*
 $
```

this is how it should probably be.

```
 # /^((?!([a-z0-9._-](at|@)[a-z0-9._-]{2,}[a-z0-9._-]{0,}(\.|dot)[a-z]{2,})|\s).)*$/im

 ^ 
 (
      (?!
           (
                [a-z0-9._-] 
                ( at | @ )
                [a-z0-9._-]{2,} 
                [a-z0-9._-]{0,} 
                ( \. | dot )
                [a-z]{2,} 
           )
        |  
           \s 
      )
      . 
 )*
 $
```